# repeat python command on multiple columns

Tags: python

**Question:**

How do I apply the same python code to multiple columns of data.

**Data Format:**

I am just learning python and I have written a script to reformat my data. My current format starts with 4 descriptive columns followed by many columns of data (e.g., 1/1)

```
#CHROM POS REF ALT IND_1 IND_2 IND_3 IND_4
2L  6631    A   G   1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
2L  6633    T   C   0/0 1/0 0/0 0/0
2L  6637    C   G   1/1 0/0 0/0 0/0
```

I am trying to change the 0 and 1 to the values in the REF and ALT columns, respectively with the desired end format to look like:

```
2L  6631    A   G   G/G A/A A/A A/A
2L  6633    T   C   T/T C/T T/T T/T
2L  6637    C   G   G/G C/C C/C C/C
```

**What I have so far:**

I have written a script that will do this for an single column, but I have 100+ columns of data so I was wondering if there is a way to apply this script to multiple columns instead of writing it out specifically for each one.

```
for line in openfile:
    ## skip header
    if line.startswith("#CHROM"):
        continue
    columns = line.rstrip().split("\t")
    CHROM = columns[0]
    POS = columns[1]
    REF = columns[2]
    ALT = columns[3]
    ALLELES1 = columns[4].replace("0",REF).replace("1",ALT).replace(".","0")
    ALLELES2 = columns[5].replace("0",REF).replace("1",ALT).replace(".","0")
    print CHROM, POS, REF, ALT, ALLELES1, ALLELES2
```

Comment: Read about functions. I think they do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest implementing this using a list comprehension:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    ## skip header
    if line.startswith("#CHROM"):
        continue
    columns = line.rstrip().split("\t")
    REF, ALT = columns[2:4]
    modified = [c.replace("0", REF).replace("1", ALT).replace(".", "0")
                for c in columns[4:]]
    print('\t'.join(columns[0:4] + modified))
```

Three additions to your code:

```
REF, ALT = columns[2:4]
```

Which is a clean way to grab two elements from the list.

```
modified = [c.replace("0", REF).replace("1", ALT).replace(".", "0")
            for c in columns[4:]]
```

Which is a list comprehension to do the replace across all of the fields at once. And then

```
print('\t'.join(columns[0:4] + modified))
```

which reassembles everything at once.

Comment: Thank you for such a clear explanation.  The code works perfectly and the description makes it clear what each part does so can adjust and implement it myself in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as file_handle:
        for line in file_handle:
            # skip header
            if line.startswith("#CHROM"):
                continue
            columns = line.rstrip().split("\t")
            CHROM = columns[0]
            POS = columns[1]
            REF = columns[2]
            ALT = columns[3]
            ALLELS = [value.replace("0", REF).replace("1", ALT).replace(".", "0") for value in columns[4:]]
            print("\t".join(columns[0:4] + ALLELS))
```

You call it like this:

```
read_data("file.txt")
```

`[value.replace("0", REF).replace("1", ALT).replace(".", "0") for value in columns[4:]]`is called a "List comprehension". It looks at every value of a list and does something with it. See [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

`columns[4:]` means, look at all my columns and get me the columns starting at index 4 until the last column.

`sep="\t"` in the `print` statement means, that all the elements you pass to the print function should be printed with a TAB in between them.

`"\t".join(columns[0:4] + ALLELS)` returns a single string in which all elements are joined by a TAB. See [Stephen Rauch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42330119/5472124).